# How to make new artboard in Illustrator 2021 using Applescript?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
   tell the current document
       make new artboard with properties {artboard rectangle:{0, 0, 100, 100}}
   end tell
end tell
```

I found an old way at macscriptor.net, but it raises an error message for Illustrator 2021 version.

error "Adobe Illustrator got an error: an Illustrator error occurred: 1346458189 ('MRAP')" number 1200.

Thanks to [Joonas](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/2332/joonas), I fixed it by using negative value for height.

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
   tell the current document
       make new artboard with properties {artboard rectangle:{0, 0, 100, -100}}
   end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Not familiar with AI Applescripting, but I found this post that suggests it changed in cs5 and now the height value needs to be a negative value: [{0, 0, 100, -100}](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=37319). — If you don't need your script to be Applescript, I suggest you switch to Javascript. You'll find way more material for AI scripting in JS.

Comment: Thank you [Joonas](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/2332/joonas).